# Displaying range validator error message on html input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input type =text in html and i have this js code in js file to show error message

```
 var $form = $("#myid"),
    $errorMsg = $("<span id='myerrormessagespan' class='error' style='color:red;'>*</span>");


var toReturn = 0;
$("input", $form).each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        if (!$(this).data("error")) {
            $(this).data("error", $errorMsg.clone().insertAfter($(this)));
        }
        toReturn = 1;


    }
    else {
        if ($(this).data("error")) {
            $(this).data("error").remove();
            $(this).removeData("error");
        }
    }

});
```

I am trying to convert this code to make range validator on input type=text field .dispalying only 5 digits in the textbox, but i couldn't achieve . Is there any easy way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation) instead, especially the [rangelength](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rangelength-method/) method for your case. However, if you want to stick to the original code without using any library then I suggest you try the code below for example:

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myid" name="myid" method="post" action="/">name :
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />age :
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
var $form = $("#myid"),
$errorMsg = $("<span id='myerrormessagespan' class='error' style='color:red;'>*</span>");

$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    var toReturn = true;
    $("input", $form).each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if((!$.trim(this.value).length) || (value.length > 5)) {
                if (!$(this).data("error")) {
                    $(this).data("error", $errorMsg.clone().insertAfter($(this)));
                }
                toReturn = false;
        }
        else {
                if ($(this).data("error")) {
                    $(this).data("error").remove();
                    $(this).removeData("error");
                }
        }
    });
  return toReturn;
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/jbE7z/)